# How did Hannah dedicate Samuel in 1 Samuel 1:11?

Tags: halacha, mishna, nozir, shmuel--the-man

1 Samuel:11 NASB

> And she made a vow and said, “Lord of armies, if You will indeed look on the affliction of Your bond-servant and remember me, and not forget Your bond-servant, but will give Your bond-servant a [d]son, then I will give him to the Lord all the days of his life, and a razor shall never come on his head.”

It is said Hannah vowed a vow to dedicate the child to the Lord though its not stated what kind of vow she took.The following characteristics are more or less similar to that of a Nazarite.

*She made a vow

*She dedicated the child to the Lord

*No razor shall come upon his head

But according to the Mishnah a woman was not allowed to take a vow rendering her son a Nazarite

Mishna

[Sotah 3/8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sotah.3.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&with=all&lang=bi)

> What are the halakhic differences between a man and a woman? A man lets his hair grow and rends his garments when he is a leper, but a woman does not let her hair grow or rend her garments when she is a leper. A man can vow that his minor son shall be a nazirite, obligating the son to remain a nazirite even during his adulthood, ***but a woman cannot vow that her son shall be a nazirite***.

How did Hannah dedicate Samuel?

Comment: That's the sort of question the Nachalas Shimon would discuss at length. Unfortunately, I don't have that volume to look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question!

The [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Radak_on_I_Samuel.1.11.1?vhe=Radak_on_Nach&lang=he) on the verse asks this same question but doesn't know how to explain this.

The [Remez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Mordecai_Zacuto) [wrote](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19191&st=&pgnum=215&hilite=) (better quality text brought [here](https://www.otzar.org.il/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8/%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C#_ftnref5) but mistakenly cited as Nedarim 9:5 instead of Nazir 9:5) that he thinks that Channah didn't make the vow for her son. Rather, it was more wishful thinking and a vow to do everything in her power to help her son be a nazir, but ultimately it would be up to him to decide on the matter.

Perhaps this might explain why Rabbi Yossi seems to disagree with Rabbi Nehorai that Shmuel was a nazir ([Mishna Nazir 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Nazir.9.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=he)).

[Rabbi Yisrael Lifschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Lipschitz) in his commentary [Yachin on Nazir 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Nazir.9.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&p2=Yachin_on_Mishnah_Nazir.9.51&vhe2=Mishnah,_ed._Romm,_Vilna_1913&lang2=bi) wrote that Channah vowed that she would continue to persuade Elkanah to agree to make Shmuel a nazir, and it is not written anywhere that he didn't agree.

Rabbi Yehudah Lifschitz wrote in [Dor Yesharim Vol. 2, ch. 21](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43850&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=) that it is evident from the Tanach that Elkanah agreed with what Channah said, as it says: "Her husband Elkanah said to her, “Do as you think best. Stay home until you have weaned him. May the LORD fulfill His word.”" ([Shmuel 1:1:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.1.23?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi))

Rabbi Yehudah Shapira in Imrei Da'at suggests that though the Talmud in [Nazir 29a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nazir.29a.1?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that a woman can't make the vow for her son because she is not commanded to educate him, the [Tosfot Yeshanim on Yoma 82a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.82a.4?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_Yeshanim_on_Yoma.82a.1&vhe2=Vilna_Edition&lang2=bi) explain that in the case of educating for commandments, a woman is *allowed* to do things for her children, and so was the case with Channah.